# Will folded drywall sheets create bubbles?

Tags: drywall, taping

I am doing my first drywall project in my basement and the information I have received here has been very helpful. I had to fold my drywall into 6' lengths to carry them from my garage down my stairs.

The person who will be doing the taping for me said that I cannot unfold and hang the sheets again, because it will create a bubble where the fold is behind the paper (face). The only option is to cut the sheets completely through at the 6' fold. This will create a LOT more taping because now I will have butt joints all over the walls.

For my ceiling portion, I understand that it's better to just cut at the 6' mark because I don't want to risk sagging. So I understand the ceiling will be a ton of 4x6 boards, but was hoping to hang my walls (just shy of 8' high) horizontally with no butt joints except for the 2 walls that are more than 12 feet in length.

Is it too risky? Should I just cut them through and hang a ton of 4x6 boards horizontally? My studs are 24" apart. It feels like I have asked the same question over again, and I apologize, it feels like I am getting closer to the answer I need though. Thank you!

Comment: It's not really a lot more taping. Butt joints are easy for an experienced person, and most tapers charge by the square foot anyway.

Comment: I don't see the harm in trying to "fold" the sheets with the facing paper in tact, and if you are lucky enough to hang them without tearing huge sections away, the taper can handle the rest. Even if the paper should tear for whatever reason, your taper should be able to handle it so there are no bubbles.

Answer (score 3):

Just cut them and tape the joints. Doing a preliminary inspection of a rental unit a couple days ago, I saw three bad seams that don't warrant fixing because there's only one day to turn around the unit. A month ago I had sufficient time to fix about 15 bad seams in another unit. Houses flex around. I'm confident that this shortcut of yours would be a bad spot needing repair within 20 years. Just do it right. Drywall isn't the place for imaginative problem solving. There's a book, ASTM C840. Install drywall by the book.

Answer (score 1):

The outcome depends partly on how you handle the sheets. If you make clean, straight snaps there will be virtually no delamination of the paper face from the gypsum core. If there's curvature in the cut, though, physics demands that some of the paper tear loose when you make the snap. You must make a fold, then pinch the halves together and keep them from shifting or you'll also tear the paper away.

It also depends on how well you fasten the sheet. If the folded crease is screwed well to lumber backing it can't very well tear loose.

Yes, there is some risk with this strategy. If you're doing many sheets it's probably not worth saving a few flat butt joints, which aren't that difficult to tape once you get the hang of it. If you're doing one sheet in an area where a butt joint is problematic, it could work.

Comment: Thank you very much! The person who helped me cut them did most of the snapping and many of them did not snap perfectly, so I guess it's better to cut them and get it over with. The taper will just have to up the quote a bit if they get butt-hurt by all the joints - I did not have much of an option with my stair case. Pun intended :-) Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Goofing around with 12 ft sheets of drywall like this is absurd. For your problematic butt joint use case, I suspect that I can always substitute my pattern of cutting a shallow vee into some OSB to splice over empty space.